# Apple Freeform app: stop geometry snapping to centre

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing

In Freeform, if I insert geometry on top of an image, the top node snaps to the centre of the image and will not move. How can I move both the top and bottom nodes of the geometry?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "nodes"? The dots maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MacBook, holding the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key disabled the "snap" behaviour, I haven't figured out how to disable it on the iPad, though.

Comment: The OP is using an iPhone, that's in the question.

Comment: My bad I not notice the iPhone tag